# gcc gtk2 and CANbus merged compilation

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi, gtk

I want to compile which includes  libraries for both gtk2 and linux canbus (PICAN 1.2) compilation

problem is these two compilations occur in a different way

canbus applications are compiled where make command is used:

```
gcc -c hello.c
gcc -o hello lib.o hello.o
```

here is a weird lib.o file used, in a hello.c is a `#include"lib.h"` and `#include"terminal.h"` , when I try:

```
$ gcc -Ihome/foo/linux-can-utils hello.c -o hello
```

Several outputs come up:

```
undefined reference to `fprint_canframe'
undefined reference to `fprint_long_canframe'
```

gtk2 applications are compiled:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` hello.c -o hello
```

where `pkg-config` is used as a helping tool

```
$ pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0  
$ pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0 -L/usr/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lXi -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lpangox -lpangoxft -lXft -lXrender -lXext -lX11 -lfreetype -lpango -latk -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -ldl -lglib-2.0
```

Comment: I don't really follow your explanation. Can you first make an example program which uses canbus but not gtk2, to get that part working? Then try to merge the linking commands.

Comment: I think that the one who downvoted (I didn't) should say something about why.

Comment: You might need to post code alongside your post in order for any to be able to really help.

Comment: im a newbie in stackoverflow. I appreciate your attention very much. Lets begin with PICAN 1.2 (full tutorial is in http://skpang.co.uk/catalog/images/raspberrypi/pi_2/PICAN2UG12.pdf)
wget http://skpang.co.uk/dl/cantest.tar
tar xf cantest.tar 
cd linux-can-utils

And here is a working example
in a linux-can-utils folder is an example source code candump.c , we compile it as follows
gcc -c candump.c
gcc -o candump lib.o candump.o

here is lib.o included i dont know much of it and i cant open it in rpi but here is lib.c & lib.h
lib.c

Comment: candump.c has those #includes
<stdio.h>
<stdlib.h>
<unistd.h>
<string.h>
<signal.h>
<ctype.h>
<libgen.h>
<time.h>
<sys/time.h>
<sys/types.h>
<sys/socket.h>
<sys/ioctl.h>
<sys/uio.h>
<net/if.h>
<linux/can.h>
<linux/can/raw.h>
"terminal.h"
"lib.h"

Comment: i have tried to write a full path in a source code #include "/home/foo/linux-can-utils/lib.h" and same for "terminal.h"
i also tried to write links for gcc , but somehow they dont work and it works only when .o file is made and then lib.o is used to compile executable candump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should understand the basic of what you're trying to do, and what [`-I`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options), [`-L`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options), and [`-l`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-Libraries) gcc options are used for. Then, as you're mixing several things here, leave the GTK+ aspect out, and just try to generate the candump binary.

This can be done using:

```
gcc candump.c lib.c -o candump
```

Or to split things:

```
gcc -c candump.c                # compiles candump.c into candump.o
gcc -c lib.c                    # compiles lib.c into lib.o
gcc candump.o lib.o -o candump  # links candump.o and lib.o into the candump binary
```

The `undefined reference` errors you get are because you can't link into a binary as `candump.c` uses functions declared in `lib.c`. So when the linker tries to resolve all the symbols, it sees some code in `candump.o` that wants to call `fprint_canframe`, and the linker can't find that function anywhere in the file you've given to it. I had to `grep fprint_canframe *` to find where that function was defined, see it was in `lib.c`, and then tell it to gcc.

Now getting the arguments by hand for one single binary made of 2 `.c` files is the simple case. Things like GTK+ are made of multiple libraries and getting the right arguments can be complicated. This is where `pkg-config` enters. Some projects like GTK+ provide a `.pc` file for `pkg-config` to use. It declares the different options, paths, and dependencies it uses. So by calling `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0` and you'll see the `-l` options to provide to the linker so it knows wich library to link with to use the GTK+ 2 library. `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` will give the `CFLAGS`, the C compiler flags, like the `-I` flags that tell where to find the include files. This way when you do:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

The compiler will know that that `gtk` directory may be found in (for example) `/usr/include`, and it will be able to copy its content into your `.c` file when resolving the `#include`.

Now if you want a binary that uses GTK+, you just have to give all the dependencies: the GTK+ ones, and yours. To know how to build GTK+ 2 applications, read [Compiling GTK+ applications](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk-compiling.html) section of the documentation.

By the way, GTK+ 2 is really old, and will soon be unmaintained. You should switch to GTK+ 3 if you plan to learn GTK+.

Comment: first and second try of compilation failed 
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` canduMp.c  lib.c -o canduMp
gcc  lib.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` canduMp.c -o canduMp
but the third worked 
gcc canduMp.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` lib.c -o canduMp
now im testing it's exetution